# Identify specific observable of a concat in subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, concatenation

I am trying to download multiple files sequentially / with interleave. When a file has been downloaded, I would like to show a success icon next to it based on the id of the file. Since the files are big, this would allow for a simple download management and retry specific files in case of error.

I am doing something resembling this :

```
var finalObservable: Observable<any> = null;

for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var currentFileId = this.files[i].fileId;
    var currentObservable = this.service.getResourceObservable(this.files[i].downloadLink)
                            .map(data => {return {fileId: currentFileId, result:data}});
    if (finalObservable == null) {
        finalObservable = currentObservable;
    } else {
        finalObservable = finalObservable.merge(currentObservable);
    }
}

finalObservable.subscribe(resp => {
    this.downloadService.download(resp.result);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        if (this.files[i].fileId == resp.fileId)  {
            this.files[i].downloaded = true ;
        }
    }
});
```

What happens is that the fileId sent is always `this.files[this.files.length-1].fileId`. So basically, only the last file gets the `downloaded = true`.

I don't understand why... can you help ?

Note : I based myself on this question/answer here [RxJS Observable.concat: How to know where next result came from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608173/rxjs-observable-concat-how-to-know-where-next-result-came-from)

Comment: What version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: Hello, I am using rxjs6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Try defining currentFileId with `let` keyword instead of `var`:

```
let currentFileId = this.files[i].fileId;
```

### Explanation

currentFileId is defined in loop with `var` keyword (which defines a variable at 
entire function scope, regardless of block scope)

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    var currentFileId = this.files[i].fileId;
    var currentObservable = this.service.getResourceObservable(this.files[i].downloadLink)
                            .map(data => {return {fileId: currentFileId, result:data}});
```

On the second line of the loop body closures are created and every closure 
gets a reference to the **same variable currentFileId**. And after the loop, fileId of the last file is stored in currentFileId, and every closure uses the same value, when function is called.

A detailed explanation can be found in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/921141

Comment: Phew, fantastic ! I'm glad it was just this. Never looked into the difference between var and let before :)